# How to restrict a service account only for one application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, winforms, winapi

Can i restrict usage of an service user account to particular application by using any programming language? Means i created one service account with Domain administrator privilege to have a semantic backup or something, now how can i restrict users not use that service account for any other jobs/works. If any one uses that service account credential set i would like to have email intimation through any programming language.

Comment: Your question is both too broad and unclear. You've started by asking how Windows works.. then you've talked about a "service account". Have you seen the size of the Windows Internals books? They're so big they come in two parts now.

Comment: Use a [Software Restriction Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be alerted when a logon-related event is recorded by attaching a "Send E-Mail" task to the event log of the DC. This way, when the server sees an authentication event coming in, it will e-mail you.

[This page](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2011/01/get-an-email-notification-on-system-logon/) explains how to accomplish this step-by-step.

I'm not aware of any means of binding an account like you describe, but the easiest solution would be to prep some scheduled tasks running on that specific account, then keeping the credentials undisclosed to other people.